# Failed to build ffi gem native extension on mac

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods, libffi

Tried to install cocoapods and other React Native pod installs. Installing the libffi gem native extension is part of the process, and it keeps failing with this output:

`configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check`

The dependency is as follows:

```
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.12.1, which depends on
      typhoeus was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
        ethon was resolved to 0.14.0, which depends on
          ffi
```

I also tried to find a precompiled version of libffi instead of compiling from source but it is sadly not available in RubyGems.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running:

`CXXCPP="$(xcrun --find clang)++ -E" arch -x86_64  gem install ffi`

My CPP path was not properly configured, so I had to explicitly pass it in. Hope this helps others running into the same problem.